# R code in R-Studio to save the graph as .jpeg or .png

Tags: r, png, jpeg

When I used R , there a graph could be saved by going to file as click save as then .jpeg .

But , I am unable to save like that in R studio . So , I searched but was unable to get a code to save the graph as .jpeg or .png .

Can anyone please help and provide with the code for it ?

It would be a great help .
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ggplot you can use the function `ggsave()`

```
library(ggplot)

df = iris

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Width)) + geom_point(aes(color=Species, shape=Species))

ggsave("iris.png", width = 4, height = 4, dpi=300)
```